# How can I achieve a color grading like in this photo?

Tags: filters, color, effect

I really like the effect from this photo and I know it's color grading, but I wanted your opinion on how I can get the same effect.

The photo is available [on this link](http://thechrisellefactor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/chriselle_lim_cool_kids_on_the_block_blue_bomber_jacket_satine-3.jpg).
(The website is The Chriselle Factor and the photographer is Karen Rosalie.)

And one more thing, do you think there's a tendency in current photos to give them this kind of tonality?

Comment: I believe the effect here is "blue stairs".

Comment: I'm not just being sarcastic — look at the other photos in the series where the background is a white wall instead of these stairs. It does not appear to be a strong, artificial effect.

Comment: Her skin tone looks pretty normal.  Maybe a fair amount of contrast and saturation, but I don't see any obvious "effect".  Not knowing anything about "color grading", what is it that makes you think it's color grading?

Comment: "Color grading" is primarily a film term. [Ye olde Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_grading) also refers to still photography in the initial summary but not actually in the (long) article text.

Comment: Hi guys and thanks for answering! :) @MikeW I think there is an effect because the blacks aren't true blacks, you can see they have been processed maybe with a blue filter in Post Production, but I see the whites are creamy also not truly whites, I don't know if I can explain it very well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the photo has 3 "effects"

- Vignetting.
- Some adjustments on contrast (curves).
- A slight color grading. Probably some saturation adjustments.

I think it is a trend to give and "old look", or "film look", washed out, lost memories, etc.

With a "trend" is one of many: dragan, tone mapping, "hdr", black and white, grainy, high contrast...

Yeap, people is playing more with the photos. Some years ago only experts could do that. If someone makes an app for some effects in an affordable price more people will use them.

And yes, probably a oversaturated psicodelic colours are not a trend now. Some years ago was to simulate "pencil" and "paint" on photos. Yes there are trends.

Comment: I'm just going to point out if the trend is to give pictures a "film" look, one should just shoot on film. It is way faster and cheaper. I might just be a stick in the mud though. :)

Comment: If someone has a digital camera or smartphone, and a memory, lets say 8gb. Its cheaper to take 1,000 digital photos and apply a filter than buy an old film camera, buy a roll on film of 36 exposures, take to develop, print the images, take to be scanned... Probably is cheaper probably not.